# How to load angularJs to current page from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a button to load another page inside current page. and in that page I have a Angular js code. when the button clicked in the current page i want to load that Angular js inside specific div with classname "airlinename".my problem is when I click on the button the response shows Html contet. but I want to show the result of my angular that I defined it above ng-init.

for example it shows {{x.title}} instead of airline names that i defined them above.

this is my current page code :

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <button onclick="PostEndid(this)">button</button> 
<span class="airlinename" >
</span>
<input value="1234" class="StartCityID" type="hidden">

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PostEndid (y) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'test-js.bc',
      type: 'post', 
      data : {
       StartCityID: $(".StartCityID").val(),

      },
      success:function(response){
      $(y).closest(".airlinename").empty().html(response); }
    });
  }

</script>
</html>
```

and i have the below code inside the second page that i want to load :

```
 <dl class="dropdown dropdown11 left_dromdown airlinename marg5 ng-scope" ng-app="" ng-init="airline1=[{ &quot;title&quot; : &quot;Mahan Air&quot; }, { &quot;title&quot; : &quot;Qatar Airways&quot; }]">


  <dd>
  <ul>
             <li ><input type="text" ng-model="search9" /></li>
             <li 
             onClick="routesearchairline(this)" 
             class="routecode_list" 
             ng-repeat="x in airline1 | filter : search9">{{x.title}}</li>
            </ul>
 </dd></dl>
```

Comment: you need to compile the ajaxed code

Comment: @madalinivascu how can I compile my ajaxed code ?

Comment: using $compile https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @madalinivascu I couldnot open the link . you mean I have to use the compile in my first page ?

Comment: see the answer in the duplicate question